# how to use get the both 64/32 bit process details and processInfo from the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot using C++ in windows

Tags: c++, windows, process

how to pull the ProcesId,executablefile name with path, process arguments from the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. and send them as an array of javaObjects.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells you how to get the process IDs and filenames.  You can use [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As for the command line arguments, you need to retrieve that manually by using [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve a pointer to the process's [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure and then use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to actually read it.  `PEB` has a `ProcessParameters` member that contains the arguments.  See this article for more details:

[Get Process Info with NtQueryInformationProcess](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess)